# Creating divs that have a width of the top div in a foreach

Tags: html, css

so I have a goal but I have no idea if it's possible or not:
Here's an image of what i got: https://screencast.com/t/88ImEmMif

And code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #contrainer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #main {
        width: 600px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .parent {

        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .child {
        border: 1px solid #0EA2E8;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="anchors">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="parent">
                    <?php
                    $links = array("https://google.com","foo", "bar", "hello", "world","google.com","google.com/adwords/","foo", "bar", "hello", "world","https://google.com/gmail","https://google.com/adwords/");
                    foreach($links as $link) {

                        echo '<div class="child">'.$link.'</div>';

                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what I'm looking to do: https://screencast.com/t/ze5fCya3wpbJ

So each of the boxes will have the same width in col's depending on the length in the box.

Comment: i think you should statically provide the width, otherwise the box takes word length as width

Comment: Maybe use of `display: table-cell` and `display: table-row` on each `nth-child:before`? Can't test by myself since you didn't provide actual code, just template

Comment: the best you could do is having flex with a direction of row, but you would have to set a height

Comment: Added the complete php to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try to flex setting a **fixed height**:

example using lorem ipsum text. *(your pHp is not the HTML output)*

```css
div {/* your .parent */
  display: flex;
  height: 4em;/* makes about 2 lines before wrapping to next */
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

b {/* your .child */
  border: solid 1px turquoise;
  margin: 2px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <b>lorem</b>
  <b>Pellentesque</b>
  <b>habitant</b>
  <b>morbi</b>
  <b>tristique</b>
  <b>senectus</b>
  <b>et</b>
  <b>netus</b>
  <b>et</b>
  <b>malesuada</b>
  <b>fames</b>
  <b>ac</b>
  <b>turpis</b>
  <b>egestas.</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be using **FlexBox** on the **outer div**, applying the styles `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to make them evenly spaced and distributed inside the **outer div**. Thanks to **FlexBox** each of the **inner contents** will have their own width.

```css
.box {
  width: 600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Bulbasaur</p>
  <p>Ivysaur</p>
  <p>Venusaur</p>
  <p>Charmander</p>
  <p>Charmeleon</p>
  <p>Ash</p>
  <p>Charizard</p>
  <p>Squirtle</p>
  <p>Wartortle</p>
  <p>Blastoise</p>
  <p>Ekans</p>
  <p>Pikachu</p>
  <p>Paras</p>
  <p>Abra</p>
</div>
```